# IIS 7 - Add Content to HTML-Header

Tags: html, iis, iis-7

at the moment I'm trying to add a javascripttag into the Header of my HTML document that I'm delivering with IIS 7. 
I don't know how I can tell IIS 7 to add this script-tag into my Header, is there any module available or to I have to use ISAPI-filter for that?

I'm quiet sure someone already did this. Can you please tell me whats the best and easiest way to add Code into the HTML-Header while loading and before presenting the site to the user?

Thanks in adavance!
muesli

Comment: can you provide your code you write in header part ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand. If you want to add a javascript tag you just paste it into your HTML, If you want to add it dynamically than use server-side code (ASP, php etc)

Maybe you want the server to understand javascript file types. For this you need to add a MIME type.

In IIS you can add MIME types using the IIS manager ->

http://www.hosting.com/support/iis7/add-a-new-file-extension-or-mime-type-in-iis7--

```
File extension | JS
----------------------------------------
MIME type:     | application/javascript
```

**EDIT:**

Seeing as you want to send parameters publicly for use in the javascript, you can attach the variables to the window object and then use them in your JS file.

For example, in the header of your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.var1 = "yourstring";
window.var2 = "yourstring";
</script>
```

Then in your js file, just reference them:

```
alert(window.var1+" "+window.var2);
```

Comment: Hey @reekogi,thank you for your reply!
And yes, I want to add a javascript tag into my HTML-Header containing a URL with dynamic parameters.  

Example:  

`<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myurl.org/js.php?user=@requestingUser&currentService=home"></script>
</head>`